# Does anyone know Cisco TelePresence Server API 4.0(2.8)

Tags: java, xml-rpc, cisco

Now, I have a Java program.I want to use it to start the telepresence server.
Below is the code:

```
public static XmlRpcClient getMCUClient() throws MalformedURLException{
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    lock.lock();
    try {
        XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient("https://10.0.0.53/RPC2", true);
        return client;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

And i use below code to create a conference:

```
XmlRpcClient client = XMLClientFactory.getMCUClient();

List<Conference> list = new ArrayList<Conference>();
conference.setAuthenticationUser("admin");
conference.setAuthenticationPassword("password");
conference.setConferenceName("conference_eg");
list.add(conference);

client.invoke("conference.create", list);
```

I want to know whether this is right, because there is no environment for me to test.

Comment: [Cisco TelePresence Server API](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/telepresence/infrastructure/ts/api_guide/Cisco-TelePresence-Server-API-reference-4-0-2-8.pdf?mdfid=283645287)

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring with CXF. It's easy, and quickly:

SchedulingAPI13ServiceTest-context.xml:

```
<jaxws:client address="http://10.66.73.77:8080/ctxapi/api/v1_3/sched"
              id="client" 
              xmlns:s="http://sched.api.ctc.txbu.cisco.com"
              serviceName="s:SchedulingAPI_V1_3Service"
              endpointName="s:SchedulingAPI_V1_3Port"
              wsdlLocation="http://10.66.73.77:8080/ctxapi/api/v1_3/sched?wsdl"
              serviceClass="com.cisco.txbu.ctc.api.sched.ISchedulingAPI"
              username="foo"
              password="bar" >
</jaxws:client>
```

JUnit Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SchedulingAPI13ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ISchedulingAPI port;

    @Test
    public void requestResponseTest() throws Exception {
        GetServiceProvidersResult serviceProviders = port.getServiceProviders("(name sw Enterprise)");

    }
```